# Find circle in circles in captcha

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, captcha

I have this [captcha example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG5Yh.png) or
[captcha example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl2lN.png)
and I'm trying to get at least one coordinate (x, y), that is in the circle contained in another circle.

my first approach was to get rid of the longer curves by looking for lines via morphologyEx and removing them from the image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2 as cv

# Read image and reverse colors
image = cv2.bitwise_not(cv2.imread("first-example.png"))

# Create kernel

#first i tried this kernel
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,3))

#but this kernel seemed to work better as it doesnt remove so many pixels of the circles
kernel = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   ], dtype=np.uint8)
#detect horizontal lines
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)

# kernel2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,1))
kernel2 = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                    [0, 1, 0],
                    [0, 1, 0],
                    [0, 1, 0],
                    [0, 1, 0]], dtype=np.uint8)
# detect vertical lines
opening2 = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel2, iterations=1)

kernel3 = np.eye(4, dtype=np.uint8) 
#detect diagonal lines
opening3 = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel3, iterations=1)

kernel4 = np.fliplr(np.eye(4, dtype=np.uint8))
# detect other diagonal lines
opening4 = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel4, iterations=1)

# remove the lines from the original image
result1 = cv2.subtract(image, opening)

result2 = cv2.subtract(result1, opening2)

result3 = cv2.subtract(result2, opening3)

result4 = cv2.subtract(result3, opening4)

cv2.imshow('opening1', opening)
cv2.imshow('opening2', opening2)
cv2.imshow('result', result1)
#cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imshow('result2', result2)
cv2.imshow('endresult', result4)
```

This created the
[openings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLeqm.png)

substracting the openings from the original picture results in
[result4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az4Nt.png)

as the result was not really helpful I explored `findContours` in hope of finding the lines creating the noise which didnt work out at all.

I also had some tries with `cv2.HoughCircles`

after quite a bit of parameter tweaking I ended up with this.
[Hough Circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeYcU.png), which is
not too bad but doesn't lead to the goal either.

I wonder if this problem is solvable with just image processing or if a neural network is better suited for this task. But even then there is preprocessing needed I would guess. Performance is not an issue.

[captcha example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inycB.png)
[captcha example 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd2GA.png)

Comment: captchas are designed to require a brain. you should approach this with AI.

Comment: Maybe you try to fit ellipses. The ellipses in your image seem to always have a similiar size. Once you find a bit of curve that could belong to an ellipse, fit a center and the radii and check if it matches the rest of the curve. A neural network may learn this, but when you know the structure of the problem, using an optimization that already knows that it is looking for ellipses could work better.

Comment: morphologic operations can not detect it, need ai

Comment: @allo this sounds like a good idea that I also looked into but is there a way to use morpholigic operation with a variable kernel? What I mean is I would like to use a kernel like this
`[[1, 1, 0, *],[*,1,1,*],[*, *, 1,1]]` for example where * can be any value

Comment: morphologyEx with Hit-Miss option https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d06/tutorial_hitOrMiss.html